# HTML Video Fast Scrubbing

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, video-processing, video.js

This gif is me fast scrubbing using Quicktime on my mac.

Is it possible to achieve anything close to this in the browser I have tried tonnes of different options that don't even come close can someone explain how they do this on my Mac?

The solution I currently have via the browser is by generating a Bif image and overlaying that over the video.

I am just curious and thought it was worth asking the community what options there are?

There is a lot of conflicting information regarding this.

[image]

UPDATE

This is what I am currently doing with bifs.

https://output.jsbin.com/semolid

```
But looking for alternative options if available?
```

***NOTE: In the JSBin demo if you click the box next to the time you can enable clipping it will be a font awesome icon eventually***

Comment: You should elaborate on the conflicting information you've read so we can clarify it.  In any case, the browser needs to download data, and that's a lot of data to download.  You're certainly not going to get performance over the internet like you do for a video on your local hard drive.

Comment: Thanks, @brad I guess thats all I really want to know how close can you get in the browser I know a lot of this is depending on connection etc but I am just curious if anyone else is doing it a different way not just with sprites, bifs etc. Ive update the question with some progress ive made with bifs.

Answer (score 1):

Options...

**(1)** *If video is not fully loaded for a long time*: 
Use images to represent frames at that time. Usually done as a mosaic (that looks like a sprite-sheet) where each "image" is re-aligned with display/video area as you scrub.

An example from Youtube:
This [video (a movie trailer)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aOC8E8z_ifw) has this [spritesheet mosaic](https://i9.ytimg.com/sb/aOC8E8z_ifw/storyboard3_L2/M0.jpg?sqp=ovOX_wMGCPD2gesF&sigh=rs%24AOn4CLDSOgnJrZbrh0g2yFyTKCn0gvrSYQ) for scrubbing (keep left-button pressed down while scrubbing to see similar effect as your posted GIF).

**(2)** *If video is fully loaded*: 
As you move your scrubber along the timeline, simply trigger a seek-to (using `myVid.currentTime = time-of-your-scrub-point`). That will show the picture for that second. Basically mouse-move function alone should achieve same result as that if you had clicked (to `seek-to`) after each movement.

Comment: for option 1, plyr.io has a sprite implementation which does this - with the thumbnails over the whole area so it looks how you want

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion It works great with the VideoJS bif plugin really easy to implement and does exactly what you suggested here is what I have built with it https://output.jsbin.com/semolid but my main question is can this be done without        sprites, bifs etc